# Create a static initialise class in c++

Tags: c++, oop, static-members

I want to have a class that is used for a one off initialization like so:

```
class Initialise
{
public:
    Initialise()
    {
        m_name = "Jimmy";
    }
    ~Initialise(){}

private:
    std::string m_name;
};

class SomeClass
{
    static Initialise staticStuff; // constructor runs once, single instance
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass testl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above I find that the constructor of the 'Initialise' class never gets hit in the debugger.  Why is this?

Comment: `Initialise() : m_name("Jimmy") {`

Comment: you don't need to declare an instance of `SomeClass` in order to get the `Initialise` constructor running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't define `staticStuff`, you only declared it.

You have to declare it outside of the class like so :

```
Initialise  SomeClass::staticStuff;
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/Nhe1hG)

---

Moreover, like pointed by Borgleader, you should consider using a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to improve your code.